# Monitor keeps turning off after 10 Minutes

Tags: shell, gentoo, monitors, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable screen blanking on text console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/disable-screen-blanking-on-text-console)

Hey
I use gentoo as a server, so I usually don't even start X.
But whats a bit annoying is that the monitor keeps turning off after 10 or 15 Minutes, especially if I emerge something and just wait for compiler to finish.

How can I turn this off?
I already searched google, but all answers I found were related to X or X-based terminals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable screen blanking on text console](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/disable-screen-blanking-on-text-console): look for a `setterm` command in your init files. If you have trouble with that, say so, and we'll leave your question open for that.

Comment: i played around with setterm just before i asked the question and at first it seemed to have no impact at all... but now my monitor doesnt turn off any more... Strange because i thought that it had no effect and `setterm -default` ... so seems that gentoo allready messed around with the settings and setterm -default set them back. So yeah, seems to be a duplicate then ;)