# Screen timing out on console mode

Tags: fedora, console

I am running Fedora 28 and after a kernel update my text console screen(tty2,3 etc) times out in 1 second or less. I used `setterm -blank 0` in my GUI terminal to rectify the problem but that gave me this error: `setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank`
The screen still keeps going black.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> I used `setterm -blank 0` in my GUI terminal

You are running the command with its output directed to *completely the wrong terminal*, and with *completely the wrong terminal type* specified in the `TERM` environment variable that it inherited.

As its manual entry says, the terminal type must be `linux` in order for `setterm` to permit control sequences specific to that type of terminal emulator, and the standard output of the program must be directed to the actual Linux kernel virtual terminal device that you wish to send the control codes to and thus affect.

This is a simple matter of running the command with a different inherited `TERM` environment variable and with its standard output redirected.  (The more usual case for running this command is in a login session on the relevant terminal device, where the `TERM` environment variable and standard output will be correct by dint of that login.)

## Further reading

- [Disable screen blanking on text console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491883/5132

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are talking about. I also tried running this command in the tty2 screen by alternating between my GUI and tty2 because before I can type the complete cmd, the screen goes blank. Nevertheless that didn't help either.